# Battleship error JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently developing the Battleship game in Javascript, however, everytime a run the code there's a `Cannot read property '4' of undefined` error.

I've searched everywhere for an answer but couldn't find any. I've also tried `console.log` to see what it's undefined, which I think it's my variable tab which is the board of the game, but I can't find a solution do make it not undefined.

Here's the code where I create the board:

```
var tab = [];
for (var i=0; i<dim; i++) {
    tab.push([]);
    for(var j=0; j<dim; j++) {
      tab[i].push(0);  
    }    
}

generateships(tab, dim, 1, 4); 
generateships(tab, dim, 2, 3); 
generateships(tab, dim, 3, 2);
generateships(tab, dim, 4, 1);
```

On the last part of the code I call the function that checks if it's okay to insert a boat in that position. It requires tab, dim which is the dimension of the board, for example 10, the number of ships and finally the boat's length.

```
function generateships(tab, dim, numbships, boatlen) {
  for (var i = 0; i < numbships; i++) {
    var empty = false;
    while (!empty) {
      var direction = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
      if (direction === 1) {
        var X = Math.floor(Math.random() * (dim - boatlen));
        var Y = Math.floor(Math.random() * dim);
        for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
          if (tab[X][Y + i] == 0) {
            empty = true;
          } else {
            empty = false;
          }
        }
      } else {
        var X = Math.floor(Math.random() * dim);
        var Y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (dim - boatlen));
        for (var k = 0; k < dim; k++) {
          if (tab[X + k][Y] == 0) {
            empty = true;
          } else {
            empty = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    shiplocations(numbships, boatlen, direction, X, Y);
  }
}
```

The last function I call is the fucntion that inserts a ship on a specific location. It requires the number of ships, the boat's length, their direction and the coordinates.

```
function shiplocations(numbships, boatlen, direction, X, Y) {
  for (var k = 0; k < numbships; k++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < boatlen; i++) {
      if (direction === 1) {
        tab[X][Y + i] = boatlen;
      } else if (direction != 1) {
        tab[X + i][Y] = boatlen;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd really appreciate youre help, thank you.

Comment: What line of code does your debugger tell you is causing the error?

Comment: Click on the line number that the error shows and then look at the identifier just before `.4`. That is what is `undefined`.

Comment: I get dim is undefined if I run this code.  Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @zero298 in function generateships where it says if (tab[X+k][Y]==0) {

Comment: In that case `[X+k]` is out of bounds of your array.

Comment: @JonathanRys I have a prompt that asks the user which dimension of the board he or she wants, the var dim receives that data

Comment: @ScottMarcus the error isn't always .4 , it's always changing as I rerun the code

Comment: That doesn't matter so much. It's whatever comes just before the "XXX" in the message  "Cannot ready property XXX of undefined" that is the `undefined` thing.

Comment: If I do this ```if (tab[X + k] && tab[X + k][Y] && tab[X + k][Y] === 0) {``` I get an infinite loop.   vazio never gets set true

Comment: @JonathanRys vazio is the empy variable, I forgot to change that when I wrote the question

Comment: @Inês That's why a fiddle is great for this sort of thing. https://jsfiddle.net/ It helps you get better answers faster.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't debugged your code, but this sounds like an index vs count problem.   When you have four items and you loop through them, the indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3 for items 1, 2, 3, & 4.   Most likely you are trying to reference item nbr 4 but it's going to be at index 3 (the 4th index).  There will be nothing at index 4 (undefined).  Try starting your loops at i = 1 instead of i = 0 or better yet start your items at zero instead of 1.